# Pairs of CheckBoxes and TextViews and a menu item on the very bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm pretty new in Android development. What I want to do is to place a few pair of TextView-CheckBox so that each of them will be in one separate line:

```
<TextView> ................ <CheckBox>
<TextView> ................ <CheckBox>
<TextView> ................ <CheckBox>
```

`TextView` should be on the left side and `CheckBox` on the right side. And I also want to place "About" menu item at the very bottom. Therefore, it would look and **this is what I want**:

```
<TextView> ................ <CheckBox>
<TextView> ................ <CheckBox>
<TextView> ................ <CheckBox>
               <About>
```

What I have had so far was one pair CheckBox and TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously, when I tried to add one more pair of `CheckBox` and `TextView`, I failed -- they didn't appear. And, sadly, I don't know yet how to add a menu item to the place I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lines are probably overwriting each other. Try:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

    <TextView
            android:id="@textview2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/textview1"
            />

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/checkbox2"
            />
    <Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="About us"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp" >


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llMain"    
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="3dp" >


    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffdddddd"
            >

    <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Text 1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

      <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="#ffdddddd"
            >

    <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Text 2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#ffdddddd"
            >

    <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Text 3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>


<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About us"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llMain"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: A bit heavy on the use of layouts. Not too serious in this example, but bad practice in the longer term since the layout inflation costs are relatively high. Better to use a single RelativeLayout with relationship attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use TableLayout like this.

```
<TableLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
        <TableRow                               
             android:layout_marginTop="10dip">                                
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="0.7"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
               android:gravity="right"  
               android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               android:text="label1:"
               android:textColor="#372c24" />   
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
                android:gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow                           
             android:layout_marginTop="10dip">                                
           <TextView
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="0.7"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
               android:gravity="right"  
               android:paddingBottom="10dp"
               android:text="label2:"
               android:textColor="#372c24" />   
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
                android:gravity="left" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">        
            <Button
                 android:id="@+id/btn_about"        
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="About"
                 android:onClick="About_Click" />
       </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```